# How to set tier prices by percentage in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, price, magento-1, tierprice

Is there anyway to set up a tier prices by percentage of actual price rather than static price.

Example : A product have price $15 now in tier price i need to set 5% of price discount if the quantity is 5 or greater.

**Update**
I got an idea but doesn't know about the final step . so i am posting it here.

Steps :

1. I will create an extra field where the tier prices are set it will be a drop down where person can select the type of price i.e fixed or percentage.
2. With the every tier price of the product we store the "percentage or fixed" information in the database by creating an extra attribute.
3. Now here comes my problem how i can calculate tier price with the help of percentage attribute so that my custom tier price can come on product page ?
   In other words i am not getting how magento calculates the final price.

It could be great help even if anyone can point me to some direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a wild idea...How about just calculating the final tier price up front and just inserting the value you get? This can save you a lot of headaches and the trouble of modifying how Magento works. I can say from experience that modifying something in the "price flow" of Magento is not an easy task and for sure it's not risk free.

Comment: Yes Marius you are right, i did the thing but it worked only for simple products i have created the the additional attribute with tier price which sets the flag i.e for percentage or fixed depending on that i override the function for tierprice and changed the formula.

Comment: Do you have a solution?